# Express session secret - from client to server?

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, express-session, connect-mongo

I am using express-session with Express 4. I am confused about how I pass the secret from the client to the server. I assume that I need to pass the secret for every request, otherwise I don't really understand what the secret is for.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

module.exports = session({
    //secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    secret: 'foo',
    saveUninitialized: true, // (default is true)
    resave: true, // (default is true)
    //store: new MongoStore({'mongoDB': 'sessions'}),
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    maxAge: null,
    //key: 'user_session_key',
    cookie: {secure: false}
});
```

what am I supposed to do with the secret? and if I should be passing it from client to server, what is the best way to do that?

As you can see, Passport takes care of passing session info from client to server, but req.secret is still undefined:

[image]

Comment: You  shouldn't do anything with it. It's a secret key to sign session cookies and `express-session` will handle everything for you.

Comment: And the name "secret" suggests that it should be kept secret (not passed anywhere from your server).

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate a little more about what the purpose of it is? is it to prevent other servers from being mock servers or something?

Comment: `express-sessions` signs every session id with this secret key before saving it to users cookies, making it impossible to guess someone's session id.